# Zend DbTable get rows from referenced table from other module

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table, relationships

I am currently working an a Zend framework 1.12 based project. I use different modules to keep things separated as good as possible. My data is stored in a mysql database so I set up some db table models inside my project. The relation between the tables should be handled by Zend frameworks Zend_Db_Table Relationships. I added the necessary code to my classes:

```
class User_Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
    protected $_primary = 'user_id';

    protected $_dependentTables = array('Diagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics');
}
```

`User_Model_DbTable_Users` is the parent class and is defined inside the `Users` module. `Diagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics` is the referenced class and is defined inside the `Diagnostics` module.

```
class Diagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'diagnostics';
    protected $_primary = 'diagnostic_id';

    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'User' => array(
            'columns'   =>  array('diagnostic_user'),
            'refTableClass' =>  'User_Model_DbTable_Users',
            'refColumns'    =>  array('user_id')
        )
    );
}
```

When I now try to load the referenced Diagnostics for a User row using

> `$row->findDiagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics();`

I get an error:

> **File "Diagnostics\Model\DbTable\Diagnostics.php" does not exist or class "Diagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics" was not found in the
>   file**

When I move the class `Diagnostics_Model_DbTable_Diagnostics` into the Users module and rename it correspondingly everthing works fine. So it seems to me as if it has something to do with classes beeing defined in different modules. None of the articles I have found during my researches could give me an answer to this.
Maybe I am missing something in the main `Bootstrap.php` or the `application.ini`.

Comment: Have you declared the Diagnostics namespace in application.ini?

Comment: No I have not and it was not necessary. See below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bootstrap the module. Good info: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/bootstrapping-modules-in-zf-1-8/

I use a simple class as below:

```
class Diagnostics_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
     ...
}
```

Don't bootstrap modules you don't need, I suggest reading http://www.mwop.net/blog/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html

Comment: I need to check that. Aren't the bootstrap classes created automatically when a module is created with zf?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't used the tool

Comment: The zf tool does not create the Bootstrap.php automatically. After I created it manually everything works fine! Thanks!